# ubuntu 20.04 with zfs unable to change kernel parameters

Tags: grub2, 20.04, zfs

I have edited /etc/default/grub
 and changed

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="intel_iommu=on mitigations=off"
```

the run update-grub
then looking at /boot/grub/grub.cfg I can see the change

```
linux   /BOOT/ubuntu_pwcrh1@/vmlinuz-5.4.0-31-generic root=ZFS=rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_pwcrh1 ro  intel_iommu=on mitigations=off
```

But then after booting the change was ignored

cat /proc/cmdline

```
BOOT_IMAGE=/BOOT/ubuntu_pwcrh1@/vmlinuz-5.4.0-31-generic root=ZFS=rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_pwcrh1 ro quiet splash
```

Any explanation for this strange behavior. Anyone know of a fix or workaround.

I have to add the kernel parameters during boot, by editing the boot command. This is not practical.

Answer (score 0):

I trusted a fresh install of 20.04 with zfs. Somehow in /dev/fstab the vfat/efi partition was from the windows disk and not the ubuntu disk. I fixed than and everything works. So grub-update was updating the wrong /boot/efi device.